# How to check first textbox value is in second textbox textmode

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 textboxes:

- textbox1
- textbox2

I want when my first textbox have valid date then second textbox's value become next week like:

```
if(textbox1.Text== textbox2.textmode)
{
    txtDateTo.Text = DateTime.Parse(txtDateFrom.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).AddDays(7).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

Comment: Use the `OnTextChanged` event of the first textBox.

Comment: @Max which condition ?

Comment: I want when my first textbox is valid date then second textbox become next week otherwise do nothing.

Comment: @AzharShahid preparing an answer now, wait please.

Comment: @sh1rts asp.net have textmode property.

Comment: Sorry, yes it does - I meant to ask what he was doing with it. Azhar - TextMode will either be SingleLine, Multiline or Password. Is this really the comparison you're trying to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the TextChanged event of txtDateFrom like:

```
private void txtDateFrom_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var styles = DateTimeStyles.None;
    DateTime dateValue;
    if(DateTime.TryParse(txtDateFrom.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, styles, out dateValue))
    {
        TextBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(dateValue.AddDays(7));
    }
    else
    {
        TextBox2.Text = "Invalid DateTime inserted in txtDateFrom;";
    }
}
```

Make sure you connect the event correctly, for example by using the Designer at the event section of the TextBox.

Comment: if(DateTime.ParsetxtDateFrom.Text, dateValue)----- syntax error

Comment: @AzharShahid Updated answer, try again please:)

Comment: invalid argument error. YEs i am doing on TextChange event.

Comment: What invalid argument error? Did you add the `var styles = DateTimeStyles.None;`? And add it in the `TryParse`?

Comment: datetime style does not exist in current content.

Comment: @AzharShahid Right click DateTimeStyles -> Resolve -> First option.

Comment: method tryparse have some invalid argument.

Comment: @AzharShahid I provided 4 arguments in my answer, replace your line with: `if(DateTime.TryParse(txtDateFrom.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, styles, dateValue))`

Comment: system datetime.tryparse have some invalid argument.

Comment: @AzharShahid fail, forgot to add `out` before `dateValue`, see updated answer

Comment: I have added a picture. check it.

Comment: @AzharShahid Did you replace the if line with the if line from my new answer?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51333/discussion-between-max-mommersteeg-and-azhar-shahid)

Comment: @AzharShahid insert `out` in in front of `dateValue`, that fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Max... it's working, thanks for your help. Once again thanks a lot.

Comment: @AzharShahid No problem, had some issues in the begin (a bit sleepy) but wasn't that hard in the end:)